# How to place condition in mongoose when a field holds an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I am trying to retrieve data from mongoose and facing the below issue:

```
const Car= mongoose.model('Car', 
{
 carModel : { type: String,
              required: true,
            },
sTo:   
      [
          {
                customerId: String,
          }
      ],
}
```

index.js file data :

```
app.get('/users/:id',(req,res) => {

    Car.find()
       .or({carModel : "Maruti"} ,{sTo.customerId: "1111"}})
       .then((customerList) => {
       if(!customerList) {
           res.status(404).send()
       } 
       res.send(customerList);

      }).catch((e) => {

        res.status(500).send(e)
    })
})
```

I am trying to get the data from mongoose database with the condition (carModel = "Maruti") or ( customerId= '1111') 
I am getting the list based on my first condition carModel = "Maruti" but not getting the details of the second condition (sTo.customerId: "1111" -- having problem constructing the second condition) 
Hence if you could please help me resolve by telling me how to make the second condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try or, as

`. or([{carModel : "Maruti"} ,{"sTo.customerId" : "1111"}] )`

Comment: Hi pardeep can you tell me if the customerId is provided by the user then what will be the mongoose statement app.get(/users/:id) ---> so in place of 1111 the user provides the id